# Fetch from CoreData and Group By categories is extremely slow

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have to fetch about few hundreds records from CoreData and group them by category_id to put into sections. Below is the code for the fetchedResultController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
     {
       if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
     }

    NSPredicate *predicate           = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%d == mall_id",self.mallId.intValue];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch            = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Shop"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category_id" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors         = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [fetch setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetch setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [fetch setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch managedObjectContext:self.contextForDb sectionNameKeyPath:@"category_id" cacheName:@"root"];
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

the fetching takes around 1-1.5 seconds which is unacceptable slow for few hundreds of records. I've tried to search on the Internet for solution for days but haven't managed to solve this performance problem.

I think the bottle neck is the grouping on the database.

Could somebody please help ?

**UPDATE**

```
2012-04-02 17:57:08.872 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZADDRESS, t0.ZID, t0.ZLATITUDE, t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPHONE, t0.ZUPDATED_TIME, t0.ZURL, t0.ZZIP FROM ZMALL t0 WHERE  t0.ZID = ? 
2012-04-02 17:57:08.875 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0030s
2012-04-02 17:57:08.877 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0047s for 1 rows.
2012-04-02 17:57:09.040 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZSHOP t0 WHERE ? =  t0.ZMALL_ID ORDER BY t0.ZCATEGORY_ID
2012-04-02 17:57:09.390 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.3496s
2012-04-02 17:57:09.391 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.3514s for 16 rows.
2012-04-02 17:57:09.395 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.ZCATEGORY_ID, COUNT (DISTINCT  t0.Z_PK) FROM ZSHOP t0 WHERE ? =  t0.ZMALL_ID GROUP BY  t0.ZCATEGORY_ID ORDER BY t0.ZCATEGORY_ID
2012-04-02 17:57:09.741 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.3458s
2012-04-02 17:57:09.743 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.3475s for 3 rows.
2012-04-02 17:57:09.748 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDETAIL, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME FROM ZCATEG t0 WHERE  t0.ZID = ? 
2012-04-02 17:57:09.751 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0028s
2012-04-02 17:57:09.754 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0061s for 1 rows.
2012-04-02 17:57:09.757 SGMalls[186:707] Title: icon_foodspecialties
2012-04-02 17:57:09.765 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDETAIL, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME FROM ZCATEG t0 WHERE  t0.ZID = ? 
2012-04-02 17:57:09.767 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0022s
2012-04-02 17:57:09.769 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0042s for 1 rows.
2012-04-02 17:57:09.773 SGMalls[186:707] Title: icon_supermarket
2012-04-02 17:57:09.782 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDETAIL, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME FROM ZCATEG t0 WHERE  t0.ZID = ? 
2012-04-02 17:57:09.784 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0022s
2012-04-02 17:57:09.787 SGMalls[186:707] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0046s for 1 rows.
```

Enable SQL Debugging returns this in the console

Comment: Have you set indexes somewhere in your model?

Comment: Yes I did set index on category_id but it doesn't do any good.

Comment: Good. Is that same fetchRequest as slow as it is now when you leave out that sorting? Do you have an index on mall_id?

Comment: Yes, i have index on mall_id too. And no, it's very fast without the grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you already set the indexes, when the SQLite-DB was initially created? After reading this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697771/the-performance-of-nssortdescriptor) I tried setting an index on a property for an already existing SQLite-DB: The index didn't get created. When I deleted & reinstalled the app (generating a brandnew SQLite-DB) that index actually did get created.

Maybe you should try deleting & reinstalling. Or you could use a tool like [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) (or any alternative) to assure that your indexes are really how they should be.

Comment: Sir, I can't thank you enough. The index was indeed not created. With indexing properly now the fetching time reduce by ten fold. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Does your shop entity have relationships? If yes, try removing them or minimize them. NSFetchedResultsController fetches all associated relations as well which could be the issue here.

Comment: No, The shop entity doesn't have any relationship.

Comment: Enable the core data debugging environment variable and check the exact queries that are made.